# как подключить к iptables большой список нежелательных ip-адресов или диапазонов ip-адресов

Tags: linux, iptables

Как подключить к iptables в CentOs большой список нежелательных ip-адресов или диапазонов ip-адресов,чтобы сервер вообще не отвечал и не обрабатывал от них запросы. Метод от обратного типа ACCEPT (нескольким разрешить,остальным запретить) не подходит, так как список разрешённых намного больше. Вариант с .htaccess также не подходит, так как сервер все равно принимает запрос и отправляет ошибку. Неужели для каждого ip или диапазона ip создавать правило? Хотелось бы, чтобы iptables брал список из файла.

Comment: Используйте ipset, это модуль к iptables. там правда диапазоны вроде нельзя, придется вбивать списком. но зато работает он очень быстро в не зависимости от размера списка

Comment: Размер списка в ipset  сильно ограничен..

Comment: Если речь о http то банить по геоип, конкретно удобнее банить по AS Number. Фронт енд nginx.

Comment: А как именно это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создай скрипт для загрузки правил. например такой :

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT="/sbin/iptables"

#Чёрный список спам и бот сетей
cat /etc/firewall/black_ip | while read line
 do
    $IPT -A FORWARD -s "$line" -j DROP
    $IPT -A INPUT -s "$line" -j DROP
 done
```

В black_ip ip или r примеру подсети ip/30
Но да, создаёт правила на каждый запрещённый адрес. как вариант создать таблицу - и вносить ip в неё

Comment: А откуда брать переменную $line?

Comment: cat считывает файл, а while засовывает каждую строку в line
зы в файле не должно быть пустых строк

Comment: Спасибо, zersh! Но в твоем коде не видно, где присваивается значение переменной $line. Ты точно ничего не пропустил?

Comment: нет. это функция bash - line в данном случае будет инициализирована автоматически. попробуй )